# Prevent superuser account from logging into django website

Tags: django

I have encountered a problem in Django. When I login into Django admin using the superuser account and reload the actual website the superuser also gets logged in into the website rather than only admin page (I guess its a normal behavior as superuser is also a user). How do I prevent the superuser from being logged in into website.

```
def user_login(request):
resp = dict()
if request.method == "POST":
    login_username = request.POST.get('uname')
    login_password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=login_username, password=login_password)
    if user is not None and login_username != 'ruturajK':
        login(request, user)
        resp['invaliduser'] = False
        resp['redirect'] = True
        resp['message'] = ""
    else:
        resp['invaliduser'] = True
        resp['redirect'] = False
        resp['message'] = "Invalid Credentials"
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(resp), content_type="application/json")
return HttpResponse("404 not found")
```

The account **ruturajK** is a superuser account

[Superuser also logged in into website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBXgr.png)
The above function is called by the url in urls.py

```
path('login', views.user_login, name='login')
```

I have also seen that when I login using any other account(nonstaff) I cant login into backend

[Nonstaff user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GkpE.png)

[I see this after reloading admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmHUN.png)

Comment: If you are using session authentication for your website, you can't. It's the same mechanism.

Comment: What should I use instead of that? Guide me please